# Convert from Type to String and vice versa in swift

Tags: swift, runtime, foundation

I have a generic response serializer:

```
class ResponseArraySerializer<Element: Ball> {

}
```

Is there any way to convert that to string, so I will store that string in Core Data database, and then to convert back? Typically I use it like this:

```
let redBallSerializer = ResponseArraySerializer<RedBall>()
requestInfo.responseSerializer = redBallSerializer
```

So I what to do the same after initialization from a string (so I can initialize the object when I have only string description of the class). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25872597/5644794) describes how to use a dictionary to map a string to a class.

You can do the same thing with the various strings you store. However, generics are a bit harder to manage.

First, you need to make a `Serializer` protocol that `ResponseArraySerializer` conforms to. This protocol will have the required `init`:

```
protocol Serializer {
    init()
}
```

You then have to add a required initializer to the serializer to satisfy the compiler:

```
required init() {}
```

Finally, create the mapping as a dictionary:

```
let serializerMapping: [String: Serializer.Type] = [
    "redBallSerializer":ResponseArraySerializer<RedBall>.self
    "greenBallSerializer":ResponseArraySerializer<GreenBall>.self
]

let serializerKey = "redBallSerializer"
let redBallSerializer = serializerMapping[serializerKey]!.init()
```

Creating a mapping for just the generic type itself does not seem to work, so you have to store the whole class.

Comment: Thank you, can I save mapping for ResponseArraySerializer, RedBall, GreenBall and then use it like serializerMapping["redBallSerializer"]<serializerMapping["RedBall"]>() ? So can I use generic element type as an additional type or do I need to use all possible combinations of types?

Comment: @PaulT. Hmm, I just tried it and I don't think you can do this with the generic type itself. However, if there is only one serializer class I don't think there will be too many combinations. Also, see my updated answer for some fixes I made since the compiler didn't like it how it was.